# Como pegar valor de uma td a partir do nome da coluna

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Teria como pegar o valor do td de uma tabela pelo nome da coluna.

```js
 //index definido por numero
 $valor=$('.table td').eq(0).text();
 alert("resultado com index numérico = "+$valor);
 
 //index definido pelo nome da coluna
 $valor=$('.table td').eq("Firstname").text();
 alert("resultado com o nome da coluna = "+$valor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Striped Rows</h2>
  <p>The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para além da coluna é necessário indicar a linha. Para a mesma coluna existem vários valores, um por linha.

Comment: A sua pergunta está um pouco vaga. Poderia ser mais especifico na sua pergunta? Qual valor quer pegar? Todos os valores? O que está tentando fazer exatamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possivel sim pegar o valor da td usando o nome da coluna, mas para isso você precisa definir sua propria função pois o javascript ou jquery por si só não fazem isso. E tambem note que mesmo assim sera necessário passar o index (numero da linha) que pretende pegar o valor, isto é:
Na sua pergunta tentavas pegar o valor com apenas o nome da coluna usando o seginte codigo:

```
 //index definido pelo nome da coluna
 $valor=$('.table td').eq("Firstname").text();
```

Com o codigo acima mesmo que o js podesse fazer a operacao pretendida não poderia conseguir retornar o valor da Célula da tabla porque não foi indicada a cordenada completa. Veja como devia funcionar

```
Nome        | Apelido        
-------------------------------------
João        | Mario
-------------------------------------
Ana         | Maria
-------------------------------------
```

Para pegar o apelido da Ana Maria teriamos que dizer ao programa que queremos o Apelido e indicar a linha em que se localiza o mesmo nesse caso 2 (1 em programação)
`getColumnValue("Apelido", 1); // posição 0 seria para o João`

Veja abaixo a solução para o teu problema.

```js
var getColumnValue = function(columnName, index) {
  var column = null;
  
  $('table th').each(function(index, item) {
    //encontra o index da coluna em causa
    column = $(item).text() == columnName ? index : column;
  });

  $('table tr').each(function(row, item) {
    if (row != index + 1) return; //salta se a linha nao for a desejada
    columnValue = $(item).find('td').eq(column); //pega a celula da tabela
  });

  return $(columnValue).text();
};

//index definido por numero
$valor = $('.table td').eq(0).text();
alert("resultado com index numérico = " + $valor);

//index definido pelo nome da coluna
$valor = getColumnValue("Firstname", 1); //alterado para chamar a função costumisada
alert("resultado com o nome da coluna = " + $valor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Striped Rows</h2>
    <p>The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table:</p>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bom dia Ivan, sei que faz tempo que postou esta resposta mas me diga uma coisa, se eu quiser ocultar toda a coluna pegando o index dela pelo nome do `<th>` como eu faria?

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro Podes usar uma solução muito parecida com a do metodo `getColumnValue` mas nesse caso especifico primeiro terias que identificar o index da coluna em causa (linha 2 - 7) e depois de uma forma recursiva ou com um loop vais adiconando no atributo style `display: none` para cada `td` com index encontrado de cada `tr`.